# Javascript Recursive functions for array of objects to update or delete from array based on id key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

I'm trying to create two (2) recursive functions to "loop" over an array of objects like below.  I think the two functions are "similar" but they do two different things.

Function 1 should update the object - which could be every field in the "found" object and return the "new" array of objects, so the function needs to identify the appropriate object by `.id`

Function 2 needs to identify the appropriate object by `.id` BUT to delete that object and again return the "new" array of objects.

I've tried a number of ways (below the array of objects) - but to no avail, I cannot get the new object to return.

To note even if each object has varying/different keys, **there will always be an `.id` key** -

```
[
    {
        "type":"section",
        "name":"Section 1",
        "hassection":[      
            {
                "type":"section",
                "id":1,
                "name":"Section 1 child section 1",
                "hasMenuItem":
                    [
                        {
                            "type":"item",
                            "id":2,
                            "name":"Item 1",
                            "prices":
                            {
                                "type":"price",
                                "price":"15.95"
                            },
                            "description":"Blah Blah..."
                        },{
                            "type":"item",
                            "id":3,"name":
                            "Item 2",
                            "prices":[
                                {
                                    "type":"price",
                                    "price":"24.95"
                                },{
                                    "type":"price",
                                    "price":"13.95"
                                }
                            ],
                            "description":"Blah Blah..."
                        }
                ]
            },{
                "type":"section",
                "id":4,
                "name":"Section 1 child section 2",
                "hasitem":[
                    {
                        "type":"item",
                        "name":"Item 3",
                        "prices":
                        {
                            "type":"price","price":"14.50"
                        },
                        "description":"Blah Blah..."
                    },{
                        "type":"item",
                        "id":5,
                        "name":"Item 4",
                        "prices":
                        {
                            "type":"price",
                            "price":"14.50"
                        },
                        "description":"Blah Blah..."
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]},{
            "type":"section",
            "name":"Section 2",
            "hassection":[      
                {
                    "type":"section",
                    "id":6,
                    "name":"Section 2 child section 1",
                    "hasitem":[
                        {
                            "type":"item",
                            "id":7,
                            "name":"Item 5",
                            "prices":
                            {
                                "type":"price",
                                "price":"15.95"
                            },
                            "description":"Blah Blah..."
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"item",
                            "id":8,
                            "name":"Item 6",
                            "prices":
                            {
                                "type":"price",
                                "price":"13.95"
                            },
                            "description":"Blah Blah..."
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]}
    ]
```

My update function

```
function updateNestedObj(obj,updates) {
    const updateToApply = updates.find(upd => upd.id === obj.id);
    if (updateToApply) {
        // UPDATE THE OBJ
    }
    
    for(let k in obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
            // LOOP THROUGH THE OBJECT
            updateNestedObj(obj[k], updates);
        }
    }
    return updateToApply
}
```

My Delete function

```
function deleteNestedObj(obj, updates) {
    const updateToApply = updates.find(upd => upd.id === obj.id);
    if (updateToApply) {
        delete upd;       
    }    
    for(let k in obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
            deleteNestedObj(obj[k], updates);
        }
    }
}
```

I just cannot fathom out how to "work them" - thanks in advance, any help much appreciated.

Comment: there's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is always a string. Each time you say "JSON object", practice by saying "object" instead.

Comment: That data seems fairly inconsistent -- why is `prices` sometimes an object and sometimes an array of them?  Are you in charge of the format?  If so, could you replace things like `hasSection`, `hasItem`, and `hasMenuItem` with a generic `children` node?  Moreover, you say there will always be an `id`, but it's missing at the root nodes and other places.

Comment: @ScottSauyet makes a good point. For these kinds of questions, I stick to solutions that make _zero_ assumptions about the particular input, such as the object's shape or any particular keys that may or may not exist. However a sloppy/inconsistent data is typically indicative of other problems that will pop up in other areas of your program and ultimately show lack of clarity in the programmer's thinking. The provided solution is labeled _generic_ because it can be used for input data of any shape/structure, but you would gain added benefits by improving your data's structural consistency.

Answer (score 2):

**generics**

Let's start with a immutable `update(t, func)` that takes a value of any type, `t`, and a callable updater function, `func`. `func` transforms `t` per the caller's specified return value. If no value is returned, ie `undefined`, then `update` will *remove* that value from the tree -

```js
function update(t, func) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return Object.entries(t).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        const newValue = update(func(v), func)
        if (newValue !== undefined) r[k] = newValue
        return r
      }, {})
    case Array:
      return t.flatMap(v => {
        const newValue = update(func(v), func)
        return newValue === undefined ? [] : [newValue]
      })
    default:
      return t
  }
}
```

Immutable `remove(t, func)` can be defined as a specialization of `update` -

```js
function remove(t, func) {
  return update(t, v => Boolean(func(v)) ? undefined : v)
}
```

**special forms**

The functions can be further specialized to match your particular needs. `updateWithObj(t, obj)` will recursively update `t` where a node's `id` matches `obj.id` -

```js
function updateWithObj(t, obj) {
  return update(t, v => v.id == obj.id ? {...v, ...obj} : v)
}
```

Likewise `removeWithObj(t, obj)` recursively removes from `t` where a node's `id` matches `obj.id` -

```js
function removeWithObj(t, obj) {
  return remove(t, v => v.id == obj.id)
}
```

**examples**

Let's create some sample `data`. For what it's worth, `update` doesn't care whether it is an array of elements, `[...]` or a single object, `{...}` -

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, data: 50 },
  {id: 2, data: {id: 3, data: "foo"}},
  {id: 4, data: [{id: 5, data: 3.141}, {id: 6, data: {id: 7, data: "bar"}}]}
]
```

We'll start with a simple update on `obj.id == 1`. Note the existing `data` attribute remains in tact and a new `ok` attribute is added. All other nodes remain unchanged -

```js
console.log(updateWithObj(data, {id: 1, ok: "✅"}))
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": 50,  //  remains unchanged
    "ok": "✅"  //  updated
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
      "id": 3,
      "data": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "data": 3.141
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "data": {
          "id": 7,
          "data": "bar"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here we see a deeply nested update with `obj.id == 7`. Note the `data` attribute for this node is updated and a new `ok` attribute is added -

```js
console.log(updateWithObj(data, {id: 7, data: 0.123, ok: "✅"}))
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": 50
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
      "id": 3,
      "data": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "data": 3.141
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "data": {
          "id": 7,
          "data": 0.123, //  updated
          "ok": "✅"     //  updated
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now let's see removal using `removeWithObj`. Notice `obj.id == 6` is removed along with its descendants -

```js
console.log(removeWithObj(data, {id: 6}))
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": 50
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
      "id": 3,
      "data": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "data": 3.141
      }
      //  node removed
    ]
  }
]
```

**live demo**

Here's a demo you can run in your own browser -

```js
function update(t, func) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return Object.entries(t).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        const newValue = update(func(v), func)
        if (newValue !== undefined) r[k] = newValue
        return r
      }, {})
    case Array:
      return t.flatMap(v => {
        const newValue = update(func(v), func)
        return newValue === undefined ? [] : [newValue]
      })
    default:
      return t
  }
}

function remove(t, func) {
  return update(t, v => Boolean(func(v)) ? undefined : v)
}

function updateWithObj(t, obj) {
  return update(t, v => v.id == obj.id ? {...v, ...obj} : v)
}

function removeWithObj(t, obj) {
  return remove(t, v => v.id == obj.id)
}

const data = [
  {id: 1, data: 50 },
  {id: 2, data: {id: 3, data: "foo"}},
  {id: 4, data: [{id: 5, data: 3.141}, {id: 6, data: {id: 7, data: "bar"}}]}
]

console.log(updateWithObj(data, {id: 1, ok: "✅"}))
console.log(updateWithObj(data, {id: 7, data: 0.123, ok: "✅"}))
console.log(removeWithObj(data, {id: 6}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**why undefined?**

@Scott's comment draws attention to use of `undefined` as the mechanism for removal. I have always advocated for the programmer to reserve the right to use `undefined` for her/his particular needs. If a user gives `undefined` to a program, they can expect **undefined** behavior. For `update`, the `undefined` value is explicitly used to make a value **not defined**, or **not there**, ie remove it.

Other reasons support this choice. In most cases, an object with an explicitly `undefined` key behaves the same as one without the key. If the user really wants a var/key to be present but not yet set to a value, this is the perfect use of `null` -

```js
const a = { foo: undefined }  // foo is defined, but also not defined ??
const b = {}                  // does not have foo
console.log(a.foo, b.foo)     // same behavior
// undefined undefined
```

`JSON` considers an `undefined` as "not defined" and so removes it when serializing an object -

```js
const o = { a: undefined, b: null, c: false, d: 0, e: "" }
const j = JSON.stringify(o)

// "a" is not defined, so it's not serialized
console.log(j)

// looking for "a"? it's not defined :D
console.log(JSON.parse(j).a)

// undefined input gives undefined output. it's not defined :D
console.log(JSON.stringify(undefined))
```

[ReScript](https://rescript-lang.org) plainly encodes `None` (ie "no value") as `undefined` in its [Option](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/null-undefined-option) module. Any `Some(value)` is represented as `value` -

```
// rescript
let foo = Some(1)

switch foo {
  | Some(z) => Js.log(z)
  | None => Js.log("no value")
}
```

```js
// compiled javascript
var foo = 1;

if (foo !== undefined) {
  console.log(foo);
} else {
  console.log("no value");
}
```

**explicit symbol**

Maybe none of that convinces you and your fragile program still depends on having that `undefined` appear in the output. An explicit `none` [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) can be used to signal to `update` that a particular value should be removed -

```js
const none = Symbol() // ✅ removal sentinel
```

```js
function update(t, func) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return Object.entries(t).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        const newValue = update(func(v), func)
        if (newValue !== none) r[k] = newValue // ✅
        return r
      }, {})
    case Array:
      return t.flatMap(v => {
        const newValue = update(func(v), func)
        return newValue === none ? [] : [newValue] // ✅
      })
    default:
      return t
  }
}
```

```js
function remove(t, func) {
  return update(t, v => Boolean(func(v)) ? none : v) // ✅
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate this technique, I worry a bit about it disallowing `undefined` values.  I've sometimes written something similar in which your function must return an *array* of values.  An empty array would be the equivalent of a `delete`, a single-valued array would be like a `map`, and a multiple-values array vaguely like an `unfold` (and would be useful on an array, but not an object.)  It's definitely more awkward, but from that, we can build our simpler functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Scott. Any distinct value can be used, such as `const none = Symbol()` and `update` can check for that. I can make an edit on the post later today.

Comment: @ScottSauyet in making this edit I'm realizing how challenging it is to communicate about `undefined`. The difference between `undefined` and `null` is minor yet major. Ironic that educators give no time to the concept of nothingness; it's equally important as the concept of existence :D

Comment: Yes, it's an extremely awkward part of the language.  I used to simply make the distinction that `null` is the programmer-friendly symbol of nothingness and `undefined` is a more fundamental "hey, your function didn't return" token.  But whenever I try to take parametricity into account, we can't use that notion.  This is one of the few strong FP-JS mismatches I run across.

Comment: And I use `undefined` all the times in recursive calls where I destructure an array parameter.  I know that using `const None = Symbol();  const foo = ([x = None, ...xs]) => /* ... */` is safer, but I still have a hard time doing so.

Comment: Agreed. My biggest pet peeve with that `None` is begging to be part of the global scope. `import`ing it separately is annoying, defining it in each module that needs it is annoying too. JavaScript really needs a native `Option` type. Just think about how easy it would be to add, too :D